# Inequality involving maximum of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Today, my Calculus teacher has used the following inequality without proving it, can someone give me a hint about its proof?

Let $K$ be a compact in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $f,g$  two continuous function over $K$. 
Then, it is satisfied that

$$\frac{\max\{\|f(x)+g(x)\|:x\in K\}}{1+\max\{\|f(x)+g(x)\|:x\in K\}}\leq  \frac{\max\{\|f(x)\|:x\in K\}}{1+\max\{\|f(x)\|:x\in K\}}+\frac{\max\{\|g(x)\|:x\in K\}}{1+\max\{\|g(x)\|:x\in K\}},$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the usual norm in $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if $d$ is a metric, then so is $\tilde{d}=\frac{d}{1+d}$. This is then just the triangle inequality for the metric $\tilde{d}$ where $d(f,g)=\max_{x\in K}||f(x)-g(x)||$. This is a standard way to define a bounded metric on a given metric space.

To prove the triangle inequality (the hard part of proving $\frac{d}{1+d}$ defines a metric to begin with), examine the function $t\mapsto \frac{t}{1+t}$.

Answer (score 2):

This boils down to

> Let $f$ be a suitable function. If $a,b,c\ge 0$ and $c\le a+b$, then $f(c)\le f(a)+f(b)$.

Here "suitable" means

1. $ f$ is non-decreasing on $[0,\infty)$
2. $f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y)$

Indeed, from these properties, we obtain $f(c)\le f(a+b)\le f(a)+f(b)$.
In your question, $f(x)=\frac x{1+x}=1-\frac1{1+x}$. This is clearly non-decreasing for $x\ge0$.
And 
$$f(x)+f(y)=\frac x{1+x}+\frac y{1+y}=\frac{x+y+2xy}{1+x+y+xy}\ge\frac{x+y+xy}{1+x+y+xy}=f(x+y+xy)\ge f(x+y) $$